# Sql Server : Select from 4 tables with distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct, distinct-values

**Table** `BASECASE(CaseNo, PID)`

```
CaseNo| PID
===========
10    | 21
11    | 23
```

**Table** `CHECKUP(ChkNo, CaseNo, CTime, PID)`

```
ChkNo| CaseNo| CTime                  | PID
============================================
1    | 10    | 13 Jan 2014 03:05:15 PM| 21
2    | 11    | 17 Jan 2014 04:13:25 PM| 23
3    | 10    | 29 Mar 2014 02:45:34 PM| 21
```

**Table** `DIAGNOSIS(CheckupNumber, Region, Value)`

```
ChkNo| Region| Value
=====================
1    | AAA   | CCC
1    | BBB   | AAA
1    | CCC   | CCC
2    | DDD   | HHH
3    | BBB   | BBB
3    | AAA   | BBB
```

**Table** `PATIENT(PID, Name)`

```
PID| Name
==========
21 | John
22 | Smith
23 | Harry
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT B.CaseNo AS CNum, B.PID AS PatientID, C.CTime AS CTime, P.Name AS Name, D.ChkNo AS CheckupNumber, MAX(D.Region+'     '+D.Value) AS Disease 
FROM BASECASE B, CHECKUP C, PATIENT P, DIAGNOSIS D 
WHERE D.ChkNo LIKE C.ChkNo AND C.CaseNo LIKE B.CaseNo AND P.PID LIKE B.PID AND C.CTime >='1 Jan 2014' AND C.CTime <'1 Jan 2015' AND (D.Region LIKE '%AAA%' OR D.Value LIKE '%AAA%') 
GROUP BY B.CaseNo, B.PID, C.CTime, P.Name, D.ChkNo 
ORDER BY C.CTime ASC
```

Expected Result :

```
CaseNo| CTime                   | PID| Name| DISEASE| ChkNo
===========================================================
10    | 13 Jan 2014 03:05:15 PM | 21 | John| AAA CCC| 1
```

Result Occurred:

```
CaseNo| CTime                   | PID| Name| DISEASE| ChkNo
===========================================================
10    | 13 Jan 2014 03:05:15 PM | 21 | John| AAA CCC| 1
10    | 29 Mar 2014 02:45:34 PM | 21 | John| AAA BBB| 3
```

Logic:

Here we need to see if Region or Value of DIAGNOSIS is '%AAA%',

If we find Region or Value is '%AAA%' then we need to display the corresponding(CaseNo, ChkNo, PID, Name, CTime FROM **BASECASE, CHECKUP and PATIENT**

But CaseNo should not be repeated.


Select

MAX(Region+' '+Value) from **DIAGNOSIS**[(Region or Value)='%AAA%']

DISTINCT(CaseNo), PatientID from **BASECASE**

CheckupNo, CTime from **CHECKUP**[CTime>'1 Jan 2014' and CTime<'1 Jan 2015']

Name from **PATIENT**

How do I to sort this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT B.CaseNo AS CNum, B.PID AS PatientID, C.CTime AS CTime, P.Name AS Name, D.ChkNo AS CheckupNumber, (D.Region + '     ' + D.Value ) AS Disease, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.caseno ORDER BY c.ChkNo) rn FROM   DIAGNOSIS D
    JOIN CHECKUP C ON D.chkno = C.ChkNo
    JOIN BASECASE B ON B.CaseNo = C.CaseNo
    JOIN PATIENT P ON B.PID = P.PID
    WHERE
         C.CTime >= '1 Jan 2014' AND C.CTime < '1 Jan 2015'
         AND (D.Region LIKE '%AAA%' OR D.Value LIKE '%AAA%')
) AS t WHERE  rn = 1
```

NOTE : You can change the condition `ORDER BY c.ChkNo` to something like `ORDER BY c.CTime` to get the one which has minimum `CTime` or `ORDER BY c.CTime DESC` to get the one which has maximum `CTime` among the rows which have same `c.caseno`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (If not working Update your status)

```
  SELECT B.CaseNo AS CNum, B.PID AS PatientID, C.CTime AS CTime, P.Name AS Name, D.CheckupNumber AS CheckupNumber, MAX(D.Region+'     '+D.Value) AS Disease 
FROM BASECASE B, CHECKUP C, pATIENT P, DIAGNOSIS D 
WHERE D.CheckupNumber LIKE C.ChkNo AND C.CaseNo LIKE B.CaseNo AND P.PID LIKE B.PID AND C.CTime >='1 Jan 2014' AND C.CTime <'1 Jan 2015' AND (D.Region LIKE '%AAA%' OR D.Value LIKE '%AAA%') 
GROUP BY B.CaseNo, B.PID, C.CTime, P.Name, D.CheckupNumber 
ORDER BY C.CTime ASC
```

Comment: Error occurred : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: Error Occured : The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Ya, the problem is the order by class. I changed the code. I am not sure which order you want. Change the order by class with c.caseno, c.CTime or C.ChkNo based on your requirement

Comment: We still have an error :
Column 'CHECKUP.CaseNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Column 'CHECKUP.CaseNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.